# using Qr code to extract information from an api flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, qr-code, flutter-qrcode

I am trying to use Qr code scanner to extract information of the user for example user's picture, display name etc, by scanning a Qrcode with an endpoint as the message and passing the data data to a bottom modal. so, after the Qrcode is scanned and data is extracted, it should bring out the bottom modal with the details. it worked when I inputted the endpoint url, but the scanner kept on returning a result multiple times causing the modal to show multiple times, I want a situation where each time I scan the modal shows once.

scanner page

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';
import 'package:scanner_test/get_profile.dart';
import 'package:scanner_test/responsive.dart';

class QrScanner extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String pageName = '/qrScannnerPage';
  const QrScanner({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QrScanner> createState() => _QrScannerState();
}

class _QrScannerState extends State<QrScanner> {
  final qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;
  Responsive responsive = Responsive();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  GetProfile? profile;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      controller!.pauseCamera();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      controller!.resumeCamera();
    }
  }

  @override
  void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState!
        .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(value)));
  }

  Future<GetProfile?> getProfileData(String url) async {
    try {
      // String token =
      // Provider.of<TokenProvider>(context, listen: false).userToken;
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final item = json.decode(response.body);
        print(response.body);
        profile = GetProfile.fromJson(item);
        showQrModal();
      } else {
        print("error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
    return profile;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(responsive.heightMargin(context, 70)),
          child: AppBar(
            title: Text("Scan an xProfile",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff212121),
                    fontSize: responsive.heightMargin(context, 22),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),

            centerTitle: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,

            //elevation: 50.0,
            leading: IconButton(
              color: Color(0xff212121),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              tooltip: 'Menu Icon',
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildQrView(context),
            Positioned(
                bottom: responsive.heightMargin(context, 92),
                child: buildresult())
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget buildresult() {
    return //getProfileData("") != null
        // ? showQrModal()
        Text("Please hold the camera at the QRcode",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xffffffff),
                fontSize: responsive.heightMargin(context, 18),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400));
  }

  Widget buildQrView(BuildContext context) {
    return QRView(
      key: qrKey,
      onQRViewCreated: onQRViewCreated,
      overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
        borderColor: Color(0xff6FCF97),
        borderRadius: responsive.heightMargin(context, 35),
        borderLength: responsive.heightMargin(context, 70),
        borderWidth: responsive.widthMargin(context, 10),
        cutOutSize: responsive.widthMargin(context, 380),
      ),
    );
  }

  showQrModal() {
    return showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
              height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 381),
              width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 414),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  responsive.widthMargin(context, 7),
                  0,
                  responsive.widthMargin(context, 7),
                  responsive.heightMargin(context, 7)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft:
                          Radius.circular(responsive.heightMargin(context, 40)),
                      topRight:
                          Radius.circular(responsive.heightMargin(context, 40)),
                      bottomLeft:
                          Radius.circular(responsive.heightMargin(context, 40)),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(
                          responsive.heightMargin(context, 40)))),
              child: Column(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 17),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 4),
                  width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 64),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          responsive.heightMargin(context, 50)),
                      color: Color(0xff000000)),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 37)),
                Text("QRcode Scan Successful",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff212121),
                        fontSize: responsive.heightMargin(context, 24),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                SizedBox(height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 15)),
                Container(
                  height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 1),
                  width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 366),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          responsive.heightMargin(context, 50)),
                      color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 24)),
                Container(
                  height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 104),
                  width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 366),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 2,
                          offset: Offset(
                            0.1,
                            0.1,
                          ), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      color: Color(0xffffffff)),
                  //alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        responsive.widthMargin(context, 20),
                        0,
                        responsive.widthMargin(context, 20),
                        0),
                    child: Row(
                      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 72),
                          width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 72),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: responsive.heightMargin(context, 28),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                "${profile!.message!.profilePhoto}"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: responsive.heightMargin(context, 16)),
                        Container(
                          width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 150),
                          height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 48),
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                    "${profile!.message!.firstName} ${profile!.message!.lastName}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xff212121),
                                        fontSize: responsive.heightMargin(
                                            context, 18),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 6),
                                ),
                                Text("xProfile found!",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xff616161),
                                        fontSize: responsive.heightMargin(
                                            context, 14),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                              ]),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: responsive.heightMargin(context, 20)),
                        Container(
                          height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 24),
                          width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 68),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                  responsive.heightMargin(context, 6)),
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 135, 111, 1)),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Basic User",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontSize:
                                      responsive.heightMargin(context, 10)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 24),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    height: responsive.heightMargin(context, 58),
                    width: responsive.widthMargin(context, 380),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Add to Connections",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontSize: responsive.heightMargin(context, 16)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            responsive.heightMargin(context, 100)),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 135, 111, 1)),
                  ),
                )
              ]));
        });
  }

  void onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        getProfileData("${scanData.code}");
      });
    });
  }
}
```

profile model

```
import 'dart:convert';

GetProfile getProfileFromJson(String str) =>
    GetProfile.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String getProfileToJson(GetProfile data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class GetProfile {
  GetProfile({
    this.status,
    this.message,
  });

  String? status;
  Message? message;

  factory GetProfile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetProfile(
        status: json["status"],
        message: Message.fromJson(json["message"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message?.toJson(),
      };
}

class Message {
  Message({
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.email,
    this.username,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.v,
    this.password,
    this.pin,
    this.profilePhoto,
  });

  String? id;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? email;
  String? username;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;
  int? v;
  String? password;
  String? pin;
  String? profilePhoto;

  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Message(
        id: json["_id"],
        firstName: json["firstName"],
        lastName: json["lastName"],
        email: json["email"],
        username: json["username"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updatedAt"]),
        v: json["__v"],
        password: json["password"],
        pin: json["pin"],
        profilePhoto: json["profilePhoto"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "email": email,
        "username": username,
        "createdAt": createdAt?.toIso8601String(),
        "updatedAt": updatedAt?.toIso8601String(),
        "__v": v,
        "password": password,
        "pin": pin,
        "profilePhoto": profilePhoto,
      };
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out this [newer package from the same author](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner)? It has an `allowDuplicates` setting which my help you with your issue.